# Random TextView on screen load Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, textview

I'm doing a kind of game using android Studio and I want to do something like nowadays game's loading screen in which appears random text on the screen.

I want to put on a TextView 4 sentences for example "Chargin one" "Chargin two" "Chargin three" and "Chargin four" The idea is to show one, wait 1-2 seconds show the next and when all have been shown continue with other things.

I have tried it by doing a Thread and setting TextView's text, but I got the next error: The only who cans modify TextView is the Main Thread. What I should do?

This is supposed to be into the Thread:

```
int num = 1;
int aleatorio;
while(num<4) {
        Random r = new Random();
        aleatorio = r.nextInt(frasesCarga.size() - 1);
        fraseCarga.setText(frasesCarga.get(aleatorio));
        num++;
        frasesCarga.remove(aleatorio);
}
```

I will post the class if anyone needs it.

LoadActivity.class

```
package es.fingerlabs.gamecohol;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Jugar extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> frasesCarga;
private TextView fraseCarga;
private int vivo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jugar);

    fraseCarga = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFraseCargandoJugar);

    frasesCarga = new ArrayList<String>();
    frasesCarga.add("Preparando Cubatas");
    frasesCarga.add("Haciendo hielo");
    frasesCarga.add("Mezclando preguntas");
    frasesCarga.add("Cogiendo sitio");
    frasesCarga.add("Poniendo chupitos");

    Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int num = 1;
                int aleatorio;
                while(num<4) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    Random r = new Random();
                    aleatorio = r.nextInt(frasesCarga.size() - 1);
                    fraseCarga.setText(frasesCarga.get(aleatorio));
                    num++;
                    frasesCarga.remove(aleatorio);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();






}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("¿Salir de la partida?")
            .setMessage("Si sales se perdera el progreso de la partida")
            .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}

}
```

Comment: But you have written that code in onCreate(). Where is the other thread which you are talking about ?

Comment: I have edited the post adding the Thread to better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to play with the views in non-UI thread which is prohibited in Android.
For your purpose, there are several ways to do it like `Handlers`, `AsyncTask`. `AysncTask` will be easy for you.

Create a `AsyncTask` like this -

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                int num = 1;
                int aleatorio;
                while(num<4) {

                    Random r = new Random();
                    aleatorio = r.nextInt(frasesCarga.size() - 1);
                    publishProgress(frasesCarga.get(aleatorio));
                    num++;
                    frasesCarga.remove(aleatorio);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            fraseCarga.setText(values[0]);
        }
    }
```

And start your task in `onCreate()` -

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have solve it by using a broadcast intent but your solution works perfect too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in the AsyncTask `onProgressUpdate()` is the only place you can update the TextView. The UI thread holds the TextView so it cannot be changed in the background. Call the method `publishProgress()` inside of `doInBackground()` to run `onProgressUpdate()`

AsyncTask is great for short operations off the main UI thread. To implement a AsyncTask you can create a **static inner** class off the activity, or a separate java file class.

`static class MyTask extends AsyncTask <TypeOfVarArgParams,ProgressValue,ResultValue>`

Looking at the above code from Shadab Ansari, `doInBackground()` is the only method that does any work in its own thread. AsyncTask sets this up for you.  To use AsyncTask you must subclass it. AsyncTask uses generics and varargs. The parameters are the following AsyncTask  .

An AsyncTask is started via the `execute()` method.

The `execute()` method calls the `doInBackground()` and the `onPostExecute()` method.

**`TypeOfVarArgParams`** is passed into the doInBackground() method as input, ProgressValue is used for progress information and **ResultValue** must be returned from doInBackground() method and is passed to onPostExecute() as a parameter.

The `doInBackground()` method contains the coding instruction which should be performed in a background thread. This method runs automatically in a separate Thread.

The `onPostExecute()` method synchronizes itself again with the user interface thread and allows it to be updated. This method is called by the framework once the doInBackground() method finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Create an asyncTask<> class do random text creation in `doInBackground()` method and finally set resulted text in textView on mainThread in `OnPostExecute()` method

Comment: I'm newbie. You mean that I should make the mainActivity asyncTask<> or make another Class. In that create a method doInBackground() in which radomly select a sentence, remove it from the array list and finalli return it? But where I make the loop in which the main thread sleeps 1-2 seconds and sets TextView's text 4 times?

Comment: Create another class of type asyncTask then execut it from mainActivity ,